# Squaring Each element with pointers (C)

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to write a C program that squares each element of an array:

Input:

```
 v = {1,2,3}
```

Output:

```
 v = {1,4,9}
```

Here is my C code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>


 void squaredVector(int *rowVector[] , int arrayLength);

 int main(void)
 {
    int result;
    int a[] = {1 , 2 , 3};
    result = squaredVector(&a , 3); /* use the address of array a */
    printf("%d" , result);
    return 0;
 }
```

The function that squares my vector:

```
 void squaredVector(int *rowVector[] , int arrayLength) 
 {
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
   {
      *rowVector[i] = (*rowVector[i]) * (*rowVector[i]);
   }
}
```

I am not really sure what the function is doing, but I assume the values of the array are being passed to the square vector function. I assume that:

```
 *rowVector[i] = (*rowVector[i]) * (*rowVector[i]);
```

is taking element a[i] and squaring it using unmasked pointers

Comment: Your `squaredVector` returns void, you can't do `int result = squaredVector(...);`

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You are struggling with what all new c developers usually struggle with, that * is driving you nuts. Please persist, once your pointer points to where it should no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a 1D array, so you should not use

```
void squaredVector(int *rowVector[] , int arrayLength);  // This is an array of pointers
```

Instead the proper function declaration is

```
void squaredVector(int rowVector[] , int arrayLength);   //1D array
```

OR

```
void squaredVector(int *rowVector , int arrayLength);   //1D array
```

Inside the function, the for loop should change to

```
for(i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
{
    rowVector[i] = (rowVector[i]) * (rowVector[i]);
}
```

Call the function in main by

```
result = squaredVector(a , 3);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do the same rules apply for a multi-dimensional array too? Like have I only been calling arrays of pointers ?

Comment: No, a 2D array needs to have a different function declaration and use in the function.

Comment: Could you show me the pattern or should I ask a new question? My textbook only covers bubble swap

Comment: If you have a specific question, you can ask. For general information, i would refer you to a good book.

Comment: Why doesn't rowVector[i] = (rowVector[i]) * (rowVector[i]) square the address?

Comment: `rowVector[i] = (rowVector[i]) * (rowVector[i])` will result in a square of address. Are you asking why `*rowVector[i] = (*rowVector[i]) * (*rowVector[i])` does not square the address?

Comment: yes... it sounds like rowVector[i] has the (made up) address of 2x0345 and doing your code will result in  2x0345 * 2x0345, which moves the pointer out of range